# How many devices supports mobile access point?

Tags: android

Is there any charts that shows how many devices can be used as mobile access point? Or maybe any device with API >= 8 (or 9?) supports this functionality?

Comment: From what I see this questions would be better be asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment, that this really belongs elsewhere, but I'll oblige...

The OS gained the ability to have the device act as a mobile hot-spot in Android 2.3 (API Level 9). Whether any given *device* will support that depends on the decisions made by the device manufacturer and mobile carrier. Some devices offer it, others do not.

Note that there are no APIs related to the mobile hot-spot feature in the Android SDK, last I checked.